# How can we run n instances of an algorithm in parallel and compute the mean of a function of the results in an efficient way?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing, c++17

I want to run `n` instances of an algorithm in parallel and compute the mean of a function `f` of the results. If I'm not terribly wrong, the following code achieves this goal:

```
struct X {};
int f(X) { return /* ... */; }

int main()
{
    std::size_t const n = /* ... */;
    std::vector<std::future<X>> results;
    results.reserve(n);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        results.push_back(std::async([]() -> X { /* ... */ }));

    int mean = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        mean += f(results[i].get());
    mean /= n;
}
```

However, is there a better way to do this? The obvious problem with the code above is the following: The order of summation in the line `mean += f(results[i].get());` doesn't matter. Thus, it would be better to add the results to `mean` as soon as they are available. If in the code above, the result of the `i`th task is not yet available, the program waits for that result, while it might be possible that all results of task `i + 1` to `n - 1` are already available.

So, how can we do this in a better way?

Comment: Summing together `int`s in a loop costs nothing. There really is no reason to put any effort into making sure that results are added to the sum in the order they are available. Probably any overhead for such event handling costs more than simply waiting for all results and then adding them in a loop. You have to wait for all results anyway.

Comment: In particular, [std::transform_reduce()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform_reduce) for summing up the return values of applying a function to a range.

Comment: @MaxVollmer The computation which is done inside the lambda is expensive. However, based on random decisions taken during the computation, one of these task may finish way earlier than others. And the computation of `f(X)` is expensive too.

Comment: Using OpenMP is another easy option if you don't have access to C++17 parallel algorithms.

Comment: @Shawn I have access to it, but I know almost nothing about how C++17 parallel algorithms work. How would using `std::transform_reduce` solve my problem?

Comment: Add the call to `f` into the lambda?

Comment: So? You still have to wait for all results before you can calculate the mean. I don't see any benefit in adding early results to the sum as soon as they are available. The 10 microseconds it needs to sum all results after all tasks are done are negligible. Just saw that the call to f(X) is outside the lambda. You should move that into the async call, if that's not possible, maybe clarify that in your question.

Comment: Kick each job off as a std::thread, used a std::atomic as a summation, once all threads finish, have the main thread divide the sum by number of threads

Comment: @MaxVollmer Moving `f(X)` inside the lambda would help to solve the problem I've currently got in mind. However, I've asked the question cause I would like to know if there's anything in the standard library which allows me to use the results as soon as they are available.

Comment: Then maybe rephrase the question or change the example, as right now people are trying to help with what apparently isn't actually what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

#### Easiest way

What about making the lambda return `f(x)` instead of x:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    results.push_back(std::async([]() -> int { /* ... */ }));
```

In this case, `f()` could be performed as soon as possible an without waiting. The average computation would still need to wait in a sequential order. But this is a false problem since there's nothing faster than summarising integers, and anyway, you would not be able to finish the calculation of the average before having summed each part.

#### Easy alternative

Still another approach could be to use `atomic<int> mean;` and capture it in the lambda and update the sum.  So in the end you'd only need to be sure that all future delivered before doing the division.  But as said, considering the cost of an integer addition, this might be overkill here.

```
std::vector<std::future<void>> results;
...
atomic<int> mean{0};
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    results.push_back(std::async([&mean]() -> void 
                           { X x = ...; int i=f(x); mean+=i; return; }));    
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    results[i].get();
mean = mean/n;   // attention not an atomic operation, but all concurent things are done
```

Answer (score 1):

You're blocking on the future, which is one operation too early.

Why not update the accumulated sum in the async thread and then block on all threads being complete?

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

struct X {};
int f(X);
X make_x(int);

struct algo_state
{
    std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    int remaining_tasks;
    int accumulator;
};

void task(X x, algo_state& state)
{
    auto part = f(x);
    auto lock = std::unique_lock(state.m);
    state.accumulator += part;
    if (--state.remaining_tasks == 0)
    {
        lock.unlock();
        state.cv.notify_one();
    }
}

int main()
{
    int get_n();
    auto n = get_n();
    algo_state state = {
        {},
        {},
        n,
        0
    };

    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
        std::thread([&] { task(make_x(i), state); }).detach();

    auto lock = std::unique_lock(state.m);
    state.cv.wait(lock, [&] { return state.remaining_tasks == 0; });
    auto mean = state.accumulator / n;
    return mean;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't fit this into comment:

Instead of **passing N functions** to M threads for N data points(X), you can have:

- K queues of N/K elements of data elements for each of them
- M threads in a pool (producers, ready with same function)
- 1 consumer (adder) thread (main?)

and **pass only N data points** between threads. Passing functions and executing them can have more overhead than just data.

Also those functions can add into a shared variable without needing any extra summation outside then only M producers can work with a suitable synchronization such as atomics or lock guards.

What is sizeof that struct?